# Is it possible to remove a dupe-link while keeping another?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question that certainly turned out to be a dupe (shame on me, I made an incorrect assumption). It was marked accordingly **but** the first mark isn't very relevant while the second definitely is.

Is it possible (and recommended) to remove the original mark (not helpful, less relevant) and keep the latter one (very helpful and to the point)? Or do we just leave it as-is for future reference?

My aim is to lave a digital footprint that will maximize the use for future readers. Perhaps it's a benefit to remove it altogether?

[Here be the duparoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55990108/display-flex-breaks-on-input-but-manages-span-and-div-as-expected)

The less relevant link starts with ["*why don't flex items...*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size).

The more helpful starts with ["*input/button elements...*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421361/input-button-elements-not-shrinking-in-a-flex-container).

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't have such badge. How would you recommend contacting "*someone else who does*"? I mean, is there a smooth way to make such an request or are we talking a case where I have a buddy with such a badge? (Which I don't, regrettably...)

Comment: I’d check with [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) as I think such request would be on topic there (I’m not part of it, so read their rules first to confirm it is ok)

Comment: @KonradViltersten: In particular because someone with a gold badge is commenting on your question (his badge is also shown in the "closed as duplicate by (gold badge icon) *user*" message so you don't even have to visit his profile to see it) you can smoothly contact him with another comment and `@username`.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's a good suggestion. Will keep it in mind. Thanks, mate.

Comment: @BenVoigt that what was done and we were two gold badge owner to confirm the duplicate [check my answer]

Answer (score 14):

Do you have a gold badge in any of the questions tags? If so yes. In that case you'll see an edit button by the duplicate link and you can add and remove duplicates. You can even replace the existing duplicate with another if you wish.

If not you'll need to get someone else who does have a gold badge (or is a moderator) to do it. You might try looking for someone like that in chat, maybe one of the rooms there is associated with one of the tags.

Flagging for moderator attention is unlikely to help as they won't necessarily know enough about the tag to know whether one duplicate is better than any other here.

Comment: I have colsed the question and both link are relevant (https://stackoverflow.com/q/55990108/8620333) [explained in my answer]

Answer (score 6):

I closed the question as a duplicate with the first link which is the [canonical one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/8620333) and is the most relevant to the question.

You question is:

> I'd expect them to spread/shrink in the same way. What do I miss?

You missed the "The Automatic Minimum Size of Flex Items" which is explained in the first canonical duplicate.

For me the first duplicate is all you need to understand the behavior you are facing because it's not only about `input` elements and it will happen with any type of element (even with `div` when you will have more content or `img` for example).

Then if you check the second [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42421490/8620333) I added later which is a *light* version of the canonical one you will basically see the same information and at the end a link to the canonical duplicate.

So the first link is not irrelevant to the question and shouldn't get deleted and is **The** duplicate to the question. I added the second one to show you that it's easy to find other related questions if you understand the "The Automatic Minimum Size of Flex Items".

Also note that there is another Gold badge owner involved in the question and he agrees with the duplicate and I know at least another Gold badge owner (the one who answered both duplicates) that for sure saw that question. If I was wrong he should have corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If a gold badge user for the question's tags is showing an interest (e.g. commenting) it would be reasonable to @user them in a comment with the suggestion.

Alternatively, you could just leave a comment for *any* gold tag user to look at .... and hope.

If your Question shows up in searches, then it is likely to come to an gold-star user's attention eventually.  (And if not ... well the fact that it is a dup is mostly harmless.)

Comment: we was two gold commenting on that question and both duplicates are relevant (https://stackoverflow.com/q/55990108/8620333)